# Advice on loopback.js vs express js

Tags: node.js, express, orm, backend, loopbackjs

Planning to build an enterprise level application using node js. Have already worked on express js for a few projects.

When researching for other possible frameworks, came across loopback js. Loopback.js, a new framework(3-4 years) built over express framework. The initial configuration and set up of the application was so quick, as i able to set up api endpoints, basic crud, acl, user auth, jwt in few hours. The documentation is bit complex and coid maintenance not good.

But for a bigger application, is loopback.js scalable and how about performance and its default ORM? With express we can write everything the way we want and in a custom way.

Need some advise and points on this. loopback.js vs express js

Answer (score 39):

As you've pointed out, Loopback is built on top of express. Whatever you wish to do with express, can be done with loopback.

The default ORM is capable of handling basic crud and querying across different datasources. If you need, You can write native queries for atleast mongodb, and mysql (I haven't checked all connectors).

Loopback is centred around models. https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/LoopBack-core-concepts.html

If your application can be broken down into model like entities, then you should go with loopback in my opinion. It saves development time, and comes with a lot of functionality built in.

I personally like their documentation. For general use cases, its enough.

Loopback is a bit opinionated framework. They have a cli tool for generating models, remote-methods, datasources etc. They even have an own eslint style guide. I find it reasonable however.

I have used loopback in production at 2 companies, we never ran into 'scaling' problems

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

Comment: The first sentence was totally illogical.

Answer (score 14):

The requirements of your application determines, will loopback.js a good, choice for your use.

Ask yourself the following question, before switching to any new framework:

1. Learning Curve
2. Does it satisfies the business requirements
3. Available Community Support
4. Demand in Industry

Loopback.js is a javascript based framework, build as an enhanced version of Express.js, as it makes it simpler to manage API's, database, tables and models.

Multiple Node.js based Framework already exist and are continuously being improved. For example, 
1. Express.js - Popular with web development 
2. Loopback.js - Popular with API Application 
Apart from these two, various frameworks exist, you have found which satisfies your requirement.

Loopback.js is node base framework and will be  compatible with the majority of operating systems, such as:
    1. Windows
    2. Linux
    3. Mac
Both javascript and the Node.js frameworks are widely used in the industry, resulting in vast community support on StackOverflow, and the documentation page. Further, loopback is used by many companies to create scalable API manager and web application. The documentation of loopback.js provides detail on how to create, develop and manage application

Comment: I upvoted not because that's the best answer but just because you tried to provide something worth and I am wondering why someone downvoted without leaving a comment that could just help you improve your answer.

Answer (score 14):

If you're working for a small brochure application which needs some minimal APIs and content management you **should** be using Express.js with some npm package for SQL (Database). But if you're working on an Enterprise application where you need to work on some complex data models you should definitely go with Loopback.js.

Loopback is based on Data Models where we can specify relationships / migrations / seedings. So its the application type which should ideally decide on which framework to choose. We cannot differentiate these frameworks as Loopback is built above Express framework.

Hope this helps. :-)

Comment: If the use case is simple enough, fastify is also a good option. Infact, If you dont want/need to use the express plugin ecosystem, I'll even say that fastify is better, especially for simple apps with high concurrency needs.

Comment: Because of this kind of comment, now we are fixing lots of bugs causing by using loopback.